# How to conditionally apply aggregate function across data set in R

Tags: r, for-loop, reshape

I have a data set that looks like the following:

```
| ID |    Date    |      Stage |
|----|:----------:|-----------:|
| 1  |  2/1/2017  | Activity 1 |
| 1  |  4/1/2017  | Activity 2 |
| 1  |  5/15/2017 | Activity 1 |
| 1  | 5/20/2017  | Outcome 1  |
| 1  | 9/25/2017  | Activity 3 |
| 1  | 10/1/2017  | Outcome 0  |
| 2  | 4/1/2017   | Activity 1 |
| 2  | 10/5/2017  | Activity 4 |
| 2  | 10/10/2017 | Activity 4 |
| 2  | 10/20/2017 | Outcome 1  |
```

I have transformed it by subsetting to keep only the contact ID, Date and Stage columns for when the stage = Outcome 0 or Outcome 1. I then made the rest of the Stage column variables into columns for every unique Activity. From here I want to count the activities in the Stage column per ID and Outcome that are less than 6 months (180 days) from each Outcome variable in the Stage column. I want it to look like this:

```
| ID |    Date    |     Stage | Activity 1 | Activity 2 | Activity 3 | Activity 4 |
|----|:----------:|----------:|------------|------------|------------|------------|
| 1  |  5/20/2017 | Outcome 1 | 2          | 1          | 1          | 0          |
| 1  |  10/1/2017 | Outcome 0 | 1          | 0          | 1          | 0          |
| 2  | 10/20/2017 | Outcome 1 | 0          | 0          | 0          | 2          |
```

Notice that the second outcome variable for ID 1 only counts Activity 1 once, since the first instance is over 180 days.

I've actually solved this with the following code by using a for loop to populate. The problem is the data set I am working on is millions of rows and actually has 50+ variables in the stage column. So the for loop is taking super long - like hours just to get through a few columns. Is there a way to do this with aggregate and apply instead of a for loop? I can't figure out how to have the function adjust for each column name and ID.

```
#current table
ID <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
Date <- as.Date(c("2/1/17", "4/1/17", "5/15/17", "5/20/17", "9/25/17", 
                  "10/1/17", "4/1/17", "10/5/17", "10/10/17", "10/20/17"),
                format = "%m/%d/%y")
Stage <- c("Activity 1", "Activity 2", "Activity 1", "Outcome 1", 
           "Activity 3", "Outcome 0", "Activity 1", "Activity 4", "Activity 4", 
           "Outcome 1")
df <- data.frame(ID, Date, Stage)
df

#desired table
outcomes <- subset(df, Stage == "Outcome 0" | Stage == "Outcome 1", 
                   select = c(ID, Date, Stage))
columnNames <- as.character(unique(df$Stage))
columnNames <- columnNames[!columnNames %in% "Outcome 0"]
columnNames <- columnNames[!columnNames %in% "Outcome 1"]
columnNames

dfModel <- cbind(outcomes, setNames(lapply(columnNames, function(x) x = NA), 
                                    columnNames))
dfModel

for(j in 4:ncol(dfModel)){
  for(i in 1:nrow(dfModel)){
    dfModel[i,j] <- length(df$Stage[dfModel$Date[i] - df$Date <= 180 &
                                    df$ID == dfModel$ID[i] &
                                    df$Stage == colnames(dfModel)[j]])
  }
}
dfModel
```